# php regex - splitting strings - one output form

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I'm wondering a good way of splitting strings by a `|` delimiter if the input strings could be of the following form:

```
"foo,    bar"
"foo       ,bar"
"foo,bar"
"foo , bar"
"foo bar"
"foo,,bar"
```

So the only possible outputs strings are as:

```
"foo|bar"
"foo|bar|other|here"
```

Independently of how many terms are within the input string.

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_replace('/\s*,\s*/', '|', $string);
```

This will handle the cases with the comma ;) If you need the one with only the whitespace too:

```
preg_replace('\s*,\s*|\s+', '|', $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
    $input = preg_replace('/[ ,]+/', '|', $input);
```

Comment: this will allow `foo,,,,,bar`, too.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick...

```
$outputstring = preg_replace_all('/\b[ ,|]+\b/','|',$inputstring);
```

to explain:

`\b` is a word-boundary, so it is looking for any combination of spaces, commas or pipes between two word boundaries.

Comment: This will match `foo,,,bar,  , , , , foo`, too.

Comment: @nick -- true. but the questioner didn't specify what to do with multiple commas; in fact, I read his last example a implying to ignore them.

Comment: This last example wasn't there when I wrote my answer and this comment. After the change your response is obviously correct. (Why doesn't stackoverflow show all edits any more?)

Comment: Ah, got it. There is a 5 minute grace period in which edits aren't logged ;)